# OS X trackpad click-to-drag delay

Tags: macos, touchpad, delayed-execution

I am so frustrated with the trackpad behavior in OS X.  If you turn on "click to drag" with "drag lock" OFF there is still a delay where the mouse is "locked" in drag mode.  That is, if I double click and hold to drag a window or slider, I have to wait half a second to let go of whatever I'm dragging.

I understand this is useful to some people, but it really annoys me and I cannot believe there is no way to turn off, or shorten the delay.

Is there anything that can be written to the trackpad plist to alter this?

Comment: yes - this is annoying. lion seems to have decreased the delay slightly but on SN it would still be nice to turn this down

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to shorten the delay, but dragging with the trackpad annoyed me enough that I wrote an app to make it easier.

It is called [Click and Drag](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/click-and-drag/id446219856?mt=12&ls=1) and lets you use the caps lock key as a mouse down toggle.

This means you can hit caps lock and then simply move your finger around the trackpad without any pressure to preform a drag.

You might like it.